# When we install a OS does only the particular drivers for a hardware gets installed or all the drivers from the Disk gets installed??

Tags: operating-system, drivers

i am basically asking this to minimise my OS disk space

Comment: Perhaps the guys on [su] will know better than anyone here.

Comment: What OS do you mean? If it's Linux/BSDs, the kernel is open to doing everything to minimize its size. If it's Windows, drivers are either builtin (and there's nothing you can do about it) or are installed separately. If it's OS X, there's no such problem as drivers, because the OS itself is limited to a small set of devices and already has all it needs.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what OS. For example, Windows installs a bunch of drivers in the hard-drive, GNU/Linux, depends on the distribuition. Some distribs, you can chose what drivers to install, besides the generic drivers.